# My object is not deleting

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript object

```
var datasets = [];

datasets.push({
    DataItem1: {
        label: "My Title",
        data: [[9], [11]]
    },
    DataItem2: {
        label: "Another title",
        data: [[139], [3], [0], [1]]
    },
    DataItem3: {
        label: "My Label",
        data: [[1], [3]]
    }
});
```

I would like to remove an item, based upon a second list. However, I'll only know the label value

This is what I've tried so far

```
var labelsToExclude = [];

labelsToExclude.push("Another title");

var myDataSet = datasets[0];
var dataToUse=[];

for (x in myDataSet) {
    var dataItemLabel = myDataSet[x].label;
    if (labelsToExclude.indexOf(dataItemLabel) < 0) {       
        delete myDataSet.x
    }   
}   
dataToUse.push(myDataSet);
```

As you can see, I started with 3 items in my object, I'd expect there to only be 2 after this code was run.

Can some one explain what I've done wrong, I have read [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object) and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to delete "x" from myDataSet, not the current item from the for in loop

```
delete myDataSet.x
```

should be

```
delete myDataSet[x];
```

Comment: So simple, this is perfect, thank you for taking the time and wearing an excellent hat in your avatar.

Comment: @AshishMishra, I know the rules here, but, as I'm sure you know, there is a time lapse before I can do it. You'll also notice I've accepted every question I've posted so it should have been clear I know how the system works! I also don't know why you feel you need to police this, but up to you I guess...